# Are quads or triangles better for games?

Tags: modeling, game-engine

I keep reading that triangles are bad to use, I still don't 100 percent understand why but I'm making some characters for a mobile game. Seeing as it is for games then would it be better to have quads or triangles or would it matter if it was mostly quads with some triangles?

I mainly ask because I'm modelling a hand and I'm having trouble connecting it to the wrist without using triangles.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2931/why-should-triangle-meshes-be-avoided-for-character-animation/2933 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99369/i-thought-you-should-never-use-triangles/99373#99373 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36270/how-can-tris-be-used-to-an-advantage/36276

Answer (score 3):

You have to distinguish between modeling and later useage of the final result. Game models are usually modeled with quads first. Edgeloop tools for example doesn't work at a tri geometry. But then exported with a triangulated geometry to have the geometry as stable as possible.

Some game engines imports quads too. And when it's static geometry then it doesn't matter. But game engines doesn't necessarily import the quads with the same vertices order than what you had in Blender. And then the faces may bend into a wrong direction. So you usually triangulate it before export, and then check if all edges really points in the desired direction for your animation needs.

When it's a game model anyways, then you can also model with tris already. When it makes sense. As told, some tools works better with a quad geometry.

Comment: So I should change it to triangles before putting it into Unity or will it do it automatically if I leave it with quads?

Comment: When it's a character, then you should triangulate before exporting. As told, the game engine might not triangulate the mesh in the needed way.

Comment: Thanks for the help again, is there a tool in Blender 2.8 to triangulate faces?

Comment: In edit mode select all. Face menu -> Triangulate Faces