# What are good practices for meshes?

Tags: mesh

Do i need force myself to create 3-4-sided polygons like on 1st picture or i can make faces like on 2nd pic?
Does it depend on future use of the model (CNC, animation etc).
[image]
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89/when-should-n-gons-be-used-and-when-shouldnt-they/95 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99369/i-thought-you-should-never-use-triangles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2931/why-should-triangle-meshes-be-avoided-for-character-animation/2933#2933

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Found this one good example in your links: "In addition to Rich Sedman's answer, as explained by Blender Guru [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZtSh4Yedafg&feature=youtu.be&t=1106) (up to 20m54s), tris, (and other n-gons), aren't necessarily bad if you can hide them. If the surrounding surface is completely flat, n-gons won't cause any issues."