# I need some insight in understanding the basic approach to modeling an object in blender

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I am trying to learn deeply about the art of modeling in blender and just CG in general of course, and I have a couple of questions that it would be nice to have answered. When one is modeling in edit mode a character for animation and texturing, are triangles attached to quads and double quads sewed onto single quads for areas like faces on characters and things like that which need more shape; big no nos? or is that okay? I have seen some do it in tutorial, but back when I was in blender years ago and never really pursued trying to understand modeling to well and would just cover up my mistakes with other stuff, I would have issues just all over the place and I am not sure if that was it. But, definitely having that question cleared up will help with the construction process for everything that I do in Blender. And secondly, does anyone have any golden modeling rules on things to avoid when modeling in Blender and CG?

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99369/i-thought-you-should-never-use-triangles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2931/why-should-triangle-meshes-be-avoided-for-character-animation https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89/when-should-n-gons-be-used-and-when-shouldnt-they https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36270/how-can-tris-be-used-to-an-advantage/