# Good uses regarding polys, tris and quads

Tags: modeling, rendering, mesh, game-engine, geometry

Since I have been modeling I have been wondering what are the good uses regarding polys, tris and quads. I try to only have quads in all my modeling but is it necessary when the goal is only to render? For export to the game engine, is it possible to leave tris? In short, what are the good uses for each project purpose? Thank you !

Comment: Tris and ngons are ok as long as they don't create artefacts, as for game engines I guess your topology needs to be made of tris

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99369/i-thought-you-should-never-use-triangles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2931/why-should-triangle-meshes-be-avoided-for-character-animation/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36270/how-can-tris-be-used-to-an-advantage/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1684/what-is-the-technical-difference-between-an-ngon-and-a-bunch-of-triangles/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89/when-should-n-gons-be-used-and-when-shouldnt-they

Comment: Hello and welcome. This question seems to have been asked before in multiple forms over time, and already has various answers but you never acknowledged any of them. We are not sure if you aware of the existing posts but none of the described techniques address your particular requisites, or you simply didn't do any research at all. Could you [edit] you post and clarify how your question differs from the suggested duplicates? Otherwise could you rephrase it to focus on a particular step you are stuck with?