# combine triangles with squares

Tags: rendering, objects

What if I will combine triangles and squares together in one object, can that make my object more broken in some ways when rendering? Do I have to make my object only with triangles or only with squares?

[image]
For example here.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89/when-should-n-gons-be-used-and-when-shouldnt-they/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36270/how-can-tris-be-used-to-an-advantage/

Comment: I am asking about if i can have in one object triangles and squares together or make object only with triangles and squares, because everywhere they talking only about one or another, but not combining it together in one object.

Comment: "Squares" are usually refered to as **quads**, try searching for that (since not all faces with 4 vertices are square). Sure you can combine both. Triangles still have the drawback listed in the linked answer.

Comment: It's hard for us to tell, if you should use tris and quads in one mesh, if you don't tell us the purpose of that mesh. Modelling for still render purposes and for animation purposes or animated and static game assets are completely different in that regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is perfectly fine to use both triangles and squares in an object. For example, the object below has squares and triangles, and it works just fine.

[image]

As discussed in the comments below, there are many reasons why you might prefer to work with squares when modeling instead of triangles, but you can definitely use both if you wish.