# Prior Blender question / answer with spacebar results, for me causes animation playback

Tags: edit-mode

I'm new to Blender, currently using version 4.0.

The answer at [Face problem in cube, edit mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82079/face-problem-in-cube-edit-mode) on the first paragraph says

> Go into edit mode, and press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all the vertices. Press the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and type in `Triangulate Faces`, and that should fix the problem.

I try this and when I hit <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> Blender goes in to some sort of animation playback loop. What am I missing?

Prior to attempting this I did *File / Defaults / Load Factory Settings*.

Comment: space bar behavior depends on the preferences. In edit mode, use the face menu instead or use ctrl+T

Comment: Thanks for the ctrl+T.  Do all preferences get "defaulted" after "File / Defaults / Load Factory Settings"?  I'm curious how my setup has animation playback set to the spacebar, or if that is the default in Blender 4.0.

Comment: I don't remember what is the default, but this is configurated here https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcoYA.png

Comment: ok, thanks for that screen shot.

Comment: Spacebar for animation has always been the default setting on installation to my knowledge unless you've changed it on the splash screen when you installed it.

Answer (score 0):

The video is trying to get you to bring up the ***Search Box*** (some setups use spacebar for this), however spacebar is default for *Play Animation* in blender (especially after a factory settings load) - for the ***Search Box*** use <kbd>F3</kbd>. You can easily pick between three spacebar actions in the keymap preferences:

[image: Pref]

[image: Search]