# Should I be concerned about non planar quads like these if I'm modeling for unity?

Tags: modeling

I'm currently learning modeling for my game, below is a mesh I'm working on which will be part of my character model for unity.

[image]

I suspect the scaling in the front face will cause some distortion for the connecting faces, so I use the mesh clean up tools split non-planar faces

[image]

So the connecting two faces are indeed non-planar faces. I tried to fix it but there's no easy way at least for my current knowledge of modeling. Should I take care of it before I export it to Unity or this kind of non planar face is OK for game models?

I tried to google answers about non planar faces in modeling, the information is mixed as some articles saying non-planar faces are no but some post also says non-planar faces especially for biological objects are not something to be concerned as game engine will split them to triangles eventually, so I'm confused.

Edit: I have read the post [Flat quads (or, why is my mesh so funky?)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56755/flat-quads-or-why-is-my-mesh-so-funky), I think my problem here is: this mesh is gonna be a part of a mech, and I also want to keep the polygons low so I'm not sure if subdividing/smoothing it is the way to do it.

Comment: Hi I have read your answer in that post, I just tried the sub division modifier and the "Simple" option does pretty much what I want as it smooths the face out to mechanical acceptable shape but not too much as "Catmull-Clark", thanks for the help!

Comment: Um, the link you posted in this and hoe answer is to this post itself.

Comment: Fixed, should have double checked before editing it

Answer (score 0):

The first answer in [Flat quads (or, why is my mesh so funky?)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56755/flat-quads-or-why-is-my-mesh-so-funky) answers most of this question, and for my case since I want to build a mechanical object, subdivision surfaces modifier with "simple" option does pretty much what I want to achieve.