# Subsurface modifier problem in blender

Tags: modeling

I have a problem with the subsurface modifier. I am new to blender.

The modifier does this:
[image: Front side]

I know the reason. It's because I have some geometry on the back:
[image: Back side]

So on the back I have a corner. This is the top view:

[image: Top view]

I know I have a problem with the corner from the top too but that is a different problem that I need to fix.

Comment: Avoid N-gons (polygons with more than 4 faces). But,most importantly, avoid non planar geometry: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56755/flat-quads-or-why-is-my-mesh-so-funky

Comment: @cegaton Thanks for the info. It fixed my problem.