# Model pinching?

Tags: modeling

My model is pinching and creating artifacts in certain areas. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need more geometry or subdivisions. The quads are too large and the vertices are not aligning in a way that creates planar faces. In other words those quads are not enough to describe the shape you are after, you need more faces where the sharp creases occur.

Comment: Read this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56755/flat-quads-or-why-is-my-mesh-so-funky it will save you a lot of the guessing.