# Does it matter if my planar quads are convex or concave?

Tags: modeling

I'm modeling static buildings for use in Unity. My quads are all planar (within one degree). With respect to efficiency and later material application, does it matter if they are convex or concave?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56755/flat-quads-or-why-is-my-mesh-so-funky

Answer (score 0):

If you worry about how your mesh might be triangularized when exporting to Unity, the best option remains to triangularize yourself.

- Add a Triangulate modifier
- Check if your surface is preserved as you wanted
- In the places where it isn't:

  - switch to edit mode and select a faulty quad
  - press Ctrl T to destructively triangularize it
  - use the menu Edge > [Rotate Edge](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/rotate_edge.html) if needed
- Export with the `Apply Modifiers` option enabled

You are doing this for static meshes, but for anyone else wanting to do this for animated meshes: do this only on parts that do not bend. Otherwise, either you can predict all possible bends and put the triangles manually as they need to be, or you need to change the topology in that area to avoid the wrong triangles.

Do understand that meshes get triangularized at the end of the day for rendering, so don't stress about avoiding triangles and putting quads everywhere, think instead about having the right edge flow and placing poles and triangles where needed.