# Why are these faces bent with no edges in the center?

Tags: modeling, topology

I was trying to model something that had the classic low poly look but this face spoils that. How can i fix it and why does it happen? This happens with a ton of other faces. I cant find any helpful videos or explanations. I checked for double vertices but this face has just 4 vertices]

[[image: 1]

[[image: 2]

Sorry I'm so vague about this - I am trying to understand what sort of approaches could be taken.

[image]

Comment: Hello, what bothers you exactly? It's not clear...

Comment: "...but this spoils that", "this happens..." - what exactly is "this"? We have no crystal ball to know which face should look how... you say "this face has just 4 vertices" - which one? And what is wrong with it?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann i have updated the picture with the face in question circled

Comment: You mean the one with the sharp bend in it? Well, I do not know "why" this happens because I do not know how you created this object or why you created it with this sharp bend - but this is messy geometry. A quad should be planar or at least almost planar. I would either select the two vertices where the bend is and press `J` to split the face there, or select all and then go to _Mesh_ > _Clean Up_ > _Split Non-Planar Faces_. Apart from that, since we don't know what the result should be we cannot give you any tips what you could have done better.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann will it help if i share the .blend file

Comment: It is simply a not flat face

Comment: As @lemon said, it is simply a not flat face. What you can do about it I told you already, but even better it would be to simply not create such a face in the first place.

Comment: @lemon how do i make it a flat face

Comment: Gordon said it above. But in this case you could also split it, change the topology, etc.

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56755/flat-quads-or-why-is-my-mesh-so-funky/56764#56764

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments shared have answered the question, but since I recently did some experimenting I thought I'd give my 2 cents.

Quads and N-gons are worked on as triangles. Since there are many ways to split up a triangle, graphics programs have to 'guess' how to do it if the geometry doesn't tell them. So for example:

[image: Ways to cut a quad into a triangle]

Now if we take all of these quads and lift a corner vertex, only one of the quads (top left) is bent differently.

[image: All quads 'bent' the same except for one]

The quad at the top left has an edge running from the vertex we raised to the opposite vertex. So we have specified with geometry how WE want the shape to be, so Blender does not have to guess.

As was said in the comments, select two vertices and 'J'oin them to create an edge where the path guiding the bend should be.