How do I fix sides being funky when merging verticies?
I'm very new to blender but I'm trying to merge vertices and the sides end up weird. I'm not good at explaining this so I'll just upload a picture. Does anyone know how to fix this?


https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56755/flat-quads-or-why-is-my-mesh-so-funky/56764
