How do i view quad tessellation in viewport?
I'm seeking a method to visually inspect the tessellation lines of each quad in my mesh directly within the viewport. Blender typically applies a smoothing algorithm upon face creation, but this smoothing doesn't always align with the desired mesh structure. To address this, the Blender team has introduced an option in Face Data to flip tessellation direction. However, I'm encountering difficulty in quickly identifying these lines in the viewport.
I've experimented with viewport shading, maximizing cavity settings, which effectively highlights extreme examples. Yet, this approach fails to distinguish shading on nearly flat faces.
Ideally, I'd prefer a colored line indicator that clearly delineates where tessellation occurs.
In this image we can see the cavity view of an extreme and subtle example of face tessellation.


https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56755/flat-quads-or-why-is-my-mesh-so-funky/56764

This link has an example gif where you show a line representing the tessellation but there is no indication of how this was done. Could you share how you achieved this result?

It is probably just a wireframe view with a Triangulate modifier on the object

Yes, that worked perfectly for me! Adding a Triangulate modifier with Edit Mode selected and using Quad method: Fixed and N-gon Method: Beauty gave me exactly the results I was looking for. Thank you!

Somebody add this as an answer, ‘cause otherwise the question will show as unanswered.
