# Problem to export an DXF

Tags: modeling, export, file-format

I created a plan then I created circular holes on this plan.

I exported the file in DXF format. When I open them with the Comsol software, I find that the plan is divided into parts like shown in the figure.

[image]

Regarding the DXF format, I add the following properities:

[image]

How to adjust these settings to get a plan that contains these holes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge around a face](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48954/merge-around-a-face)

Comment: Not work for me, I select all, with A, and then press X (or Delete) and select Limited dissolve but also not work.