# How to fill in/collapse an indented cylinder onto a face

Tags: objects, vertices, edges

I'm new to blender so still figuring things out. I need to basically fill in the cylinder so that it no longer exists. I want to close up the half cylinder on the left, remove the edges in the center, then close up the wall on the right that's currently cut into with the half cylinder indent. I tried deleting vertices and edges, but it seems that no matter what I do it really messes with the design or destroys the face.

Also, are the edges connecting cutouts in my object necessary? Any way to remove them? They seem to complicate making faces.

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge around a face](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48954/merge-around-a-face)

Answer (score 1):

Are you going to make this a super high resolution mesh later? You're going to want to clean up the faces that have 5 or more sides before you continue to progress. But that's an aside. The main thing you want to do at this point is get rid of that cylindrical shape. What you need to do about that is switch to face select mode, and alt + shift + right click the edge that flows with the shape of the round loop of the cylinder. This should select the entire cylinder. Delete these faces while still in face mode.

Now switch to vertex mode. Select the vertex where the floor of the object and the wall meet at the beginning of the remainder of the cylinder's curve. Make sure your 'pivot point for rotation and scaling' is still set to 'cursor'. Select the remaining vertex points that form the remainder of the cylinder on that side, and merge all of the points to one of the end points. Do the same thing on the other mirrored half of the mesh. Select the vertex.

If you need a more in depth explanation, lemme know.

Comment: Hey thanks for taking the time, before I read this I ended up using the merge vertices function and was able to clean it up that way. It was kind of a pain in the butt, but it worked. It's tough being new to this program because I see there's a hundred different ways of doing things, I'm just not familiar enough yet to know the best way.

In response to your comment about cleaning it up, I'm not sure what you mean by "super" high resolution, but I am planning on 3D printing this object. Would that have anything to do with having non-manifold geometry?

Comment: You'll get used to it. Other things you could have done is select by holding down alt ald right clicking an edge or face loop or box selected by pressing b, or circle selected by pressing c. with circle select, you can increase the size of the circle brush with mwheel

Comment: Here's a photo of the selection...no idea how to fix this.
https://ibb.co/SX4g4rv

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do there.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to add a photo and I'm screwing it up. I'm just trying to fix the non-manifold geometry so I can't print the object.

Comment: I see the photo. I don't know what it means, though

Comment: The photo is the result of going to Select > Select All By Trait > Non Manifold. The highlighted areas need to be corrected before I can go to print.

Comment: Go into edit mode, go to vertex mode. Press K to use the knife tool and draw lines from one vertex to another to create four sided faces. If you have a face with more than 4 sides you get an n-gon, which I'm assuming you're trying to eliminate. Try to maintain your edge flow so that it's easier to build upon in the future.