# Way(s) to remove unnecessary Geometry?

Tags: modeling, faces, geometry

I've got a problem while modelling my Anvil - after boolean I have a lot of geometry all over the mesh that I don't want. For example - there are a lot of squares in areas that are entirely flat, but any dissolving/merging that I've done significantly lowered the quality and shows problems with a   SubSurface modifier enabled

**Question**: How can I delete part(s) of edge loops in places, where I don't need them, without falling in triangulate/NGon/other problems? By-hand method also will suit me, though, any solution/councel will be great!

[image: The problem itself]

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48954/merge-around-a-face/48967#48967

Comment: I can't see why you would want to do this, but you could consider using limited dissolve on the selected area and then set the edge crease value of the border edges to 1 (use shift+E). This should prevent problems with the subsurface modifier.

Comment: @RobertRoth,   thanks for tip! That and several others kinda worked, but if to have this much unnecessary geometry is is ok and it doesn't overload things too much - than, i suppose, i'l lleave this as that.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos , a very useful link for not stepping in it in the future, much appreciated!