# How to get rid of those edges?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

How to get rid of those edges?

[image: Edges]

When i try to disolve them loop cut stops working properly.

[image: Loop cut]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48954/merge-around-a-face/48967#48967

Answer (score 1):

Loop Cuts won't work on N-gons which you may have on the top part of your mesh here.

Comment: What are N-gons?

Comment: N-gons are faces with five or more vertices.