# Unable to remove unwanted edges after fill

Tags: edges

So i have a shape:
[image]

That i fill:

[image]

and after doing a "Limited dissolve" it looks a little better:
[image]
But it leaves some edges that are impossible to delete without either deleting the face or messing up the shape, this is what happens if i delete the white edge:
[image]

Anyone knows how to fix this?
I have googled and watched a ton of YT tutorials but not been able to figure this out.

Thanks for reading my question and have a nice one!

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48954/merge-around-a-face?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: You are messing with N-gons too much. Here is an advanced solution for this problem in Box Cutter add-on: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJ7P2n1cAFY

Comment: This is OK as dissolve, limited or not, removes edges that are not crucial to the mesh and never leaves a one big ngon. And the edges are not visible in the final render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to clean all edges in your object. Since blender cant handle holes inside n-gon by one face. You can make nicer topology by manual reconecting some of the edges (or try to search for `Beautiful Fill` function), but you will need always at least two faces (two edges connected to a hole).

[image]

In some cases would be better simply select object and `Convert to Curve` type 2D. No more additional edges, just outlines.

Comment: Ok, i think i understand the issue now.
But even if i try to clean it up, when i extrude it and curve it around a circle it looks horrible:
![https://imgur.com/a/SyUkC9m](https://imgur.com/a/SyUkC9m).
Do you have any hints on how i can accomplish the same thing, an extruded pattern on a cylinder?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160720/curve-object-deformed-by-curve-distortions-artefacts/160721#160721

Answer (score 0):

A trick to simplify the faces is to select two of the split faces, and press 'F' in edit mode. This will join the faces together, and simplify the face. FYI, this does not work with non-touching faces.

Comment: Yes, i tried in on my shape but it filled the empty spaces also, so it did not work for me.