# Curve Object Deformed by Curve - Distortions (Artefacts)

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, text-object

Shaping curve object by curve (modifier) results in a terrible shape with cracked surface. Here is an extreme situation, but good visible issue.

Perspective
[image]

Top
[image]

How can I curve it smootly without adding more control points or remeshing?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

- switch to Edit mode, rotate text 90° in Z axis, so the text **alongs Local Y axis** (don't ask me why)

[image]

- all control points set to **Handle type (V) > Free**

[image]

- switch to Object mode and rotate along X axis 90°
- add Curve Modifier > Deformed by Circle, **Deformation Axis > -Z**

[image]

[image]

Essential parts of successful deformation and avoiding other issues are

- keep origins of both objects at the same place
- align text direction to local Y axis
- set handles type to Free

If a surface or shape isn't smooth enough increase **Resolution U** (Properties Editor > Object Data Properties > Resolution U). But first try increase deformation Curve, than Curve Object.

[image]

Comment: I like the *"Rotate 90 degrees (don't ask me why)"* :). Looks like my typical day with the curve modifier.

Comment: Yeah ... Even after 20 years I still don't know ... why it can't be more expected X axis ... same for object as particles. You have a tree and you have to "cut" it down before you you let him "grow" in a particle forest :) What a strange world we live in.