# curve modifier problem with applying rotation

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

[image]

hello , in the picture above i was trying to deform the plane along curve , i add the curve and rotate on Y to align with the plane , but i was need to apply rotation to make the both curve and plane have same coordinate and that work .

[image]
the problem when i move the curve point the curve normals  are rotate ( although  the tilt still zero ) and that change plane direction .

Comment: One of the never ending Q ... sorry ... this should solve it https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/160721/2214 ... I know its a curve on curve, but principle of initial orientation is the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Curve Object Deformed by Curve - Distortions (Artefacts)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160720/curve-object-deformed-by-curve-distortions-artefacts)