# How to add text to surface without causing a shadow

Tags: shadows, text-object

I have a render of a soda can that I did here:
[image]

I added the text using a curve modifier to make it wrap around the can. However, there is a shadow that shouldn't be there (Take a look at the star for example).

What's a better way of adding text to surfaces to make it look like it was 'printed' on the can?

Comment: Hello, it would be easier to integrate the logo into the texture

Comment: Correct way to [deform curved text by curve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/160721/2214) ... But as mentioned by moonboots - it would be easier to handle this by image texture  mapped by UV

Answer (score 0):

You could go into the Material Properties tab for the text and under Settings, set Shadow Mode to None. This is assuming you have a special material for the text.