# filling a polygon with holes in it with one single face

Tags: modeling

[image]Sorry to ask such a stupid question, but is there a way to fill the polygon in the picture with one single face to avoid strange edge behaviour when putting up bevel modifier afterwards.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48954/merge-around-a-face/48967

Answer (score 1):

First select the verts and make the faces.
[image]
[image]

Next select the faces and press `X` and select dissolve faces. Do it part by part
[image]

But there is a limit of amount you can merge.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and it really worked. But unfortunately, as you already remarked, there is a limit, so i couldnt accomplish it to the end. But thank you anyway, i learned another bit of blender from your comment.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't add thank you as an answer, upvote the answer instead. If you feel it completely solved your problem consider marking it accepted