# Merging faces/dissolving edges not working

Tags: modeling

i'm fairly new to blender (coming from architecture background) so i've used sketchup alot and more advance software for architecture like revit3d/bim.

The work i'm doing now is for jewelery so trying to do this in blender but even the simplest tasks are time consuming.. and frustrating. i'm really doing basic modelling but getting so many problems.

for example i just created a heart shap using half a cylinder (mirrored) and a cube. in edit mode i need the top face to be all one face but for some reason the one edge will dissolve but the pothers won't..  its the same type of edge so i cant work out what to do.
The marked yellow edge dissolved but the red won't, its a direct mirror??

[image]

if i delete all the faces then select the edges to create a new face for the whole top this also doesnt work as it only creates a faces between randon edges.. again makes no sense.. need help what am i doing so wrong for something so simple.

Image below is all edge deleted except 2d now, still wont face

[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what's going on without the blend file. If you get a change, upload it to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add it to the question. Some quick testing on my part found that if your normals aren't all facing the right way it can result in problems. You can try fixing this by selecting everything [A] and hitting [SHIFT]+[N] before filling the face. It could also be an issue of doubled vertices. Select everything again, and it [ALT]+[M], then By Distance.

Comment: thanks, i searched and tried both these fixes but nothing happens. blender just doesnt like imported files? i will add to the question The [problem is i'm having so many issues just modeling this simple shape. its 3-4 mins in sketchup.. hours of going in circles in blender..

Comment: Any problem to upload your blend via link in the  first comment? That's the fastest way to get answer if you are still interested.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48954/merge-around-a-face/48967