# Text to mesh > remesh not giving smooth enough results

Tags: mesh, text-object

I have followed every tutorial regarding text to mesh conversion and the topology cleanup but no matter what i try (remesh with smooth, solidify, shade smooth)

If i leave the bad topology, the mesh is smoothed very nicely:
[image: no remesh]

Then I do the remesh, but no matter what values i try, it always looks as if the general shape didnt get translated smoothly:
[image: remesh]

Even if i turn on smooth shading and do the right click and go shade smooth, it still looks edgy
[image: remesh with smooth]

even though the mesh is quite dense:
[image: remesh density]

No tutorial could help me fix this issue, all of them show the same procedure, is there a step in between I can add to fix this?

My goal is to turn and twist the mesh smoothly, so a dense mesh is not the problem for me, the non-smooth translation however is..

Anyone who can help?

*EDIT* Blend File:[Text to Mesh Blender file](https://pasteall.org/media/7/9/79b5fb08a4ec10ef5552bbda1e7c204e.blend)

Appreciate your time!

Sincerely
Oz

---

Okay so I almost got it!

this time I did the following:

1. Remove all effects from the text (all bevel and extrudes).
2. convert to mesh.
3. add decimate modifier and select planar -apply it.
4. add another decimate this time select collapse and reduce just so u have the amount of letters in the face count e.g. if your word has 4 letters u want to end up with a face count of 4. this ensures that your have clean outlines for each letter.
5. go do edit mode, select all and extrude, make them as thick as you want.
6. while in edit mode, click on mesh > normals > recalculate outside.
7. Usually you only have to shade smooth now and it should look smooth but that where i am confused why the shading is still so weird.

[image: Shade Smooth]

I wanted to use this as a new starting point since this ensures the cleanest amount of faces to work with.

Any Ideas?

Comment: maybe you've subdivided without smoothing, which has the opposite effect, it tends to flatten the shape. If you don't have a lower topology version, maybe try to simplify this one with X > Limited Dissolve? If it still doesn't work maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hey moon, can u please tell me the steps in order? first text to mesh right? then limited dissolve?

Comment: Yes you can convert to mesh, you should not end up with such a dense topology, maybe share your file once you've converted to mesh?

Comment: you can either extrude and bevel your text (as text) or convert to mesh then extrude

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: I have added the Blend file at the bottom. Thanks!!

Comment: Have a script that does something similar to your new edit.  Select and dissolve non boundary edges.  The face count will depend on how many holes are in character. can an 8 be made with one ngon face?

Comment: @batFINGER hope this helps, friend - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/211249/110840

Comment: Thanks Al, was rhetorical for OP to ponder. 8*)

Answer (score 0):

Use only bevel with very low amount, for example 0.003. Limit Method is set to Angle. For more precision use limit method "Weight", select edges and change weight for the selected. The weights are in properties shelf / Item / transform /edges data / mean bevel weight. To see it you have to be in editmode.