# Why can't I dissolve this edge?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, edges, extrude

Hey Im new in blender and I'm having what appears to be a simple problem, why cant I dissolve this edge? I made a plane and I loop cut it to make the hole in the middle I dissolved the other edges except for these two

[image: I cant dissolve the two selected edges]

Comment: because you need at least one edge that connects the outer quad to the inner one

Comment: Blender faces [can't have holes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/210105/35559)

Comment: I'll add that the preferential placement in this case would be an edge connecting the inner and outer edge loops at each corner

Answer (score 2):

Faces cannot have holes in them in blender like they can in sketchup. This is because blender is closer to the hard coding of 3-D graphics.

Comment: Closer to hard coding what do you mean?

Comment: @sol_keys At the base of 3-D graphics, faces are always triangular. Blender allows you to create polygons by triangulating them at the last minute before sending the data into a render engine.

Comment: Then how can you cut holes in meshes?

Comment: @sol_keys Make a torus and find out!