# How can I remove these unnecessary edges?

Tags: faces, edges, geometry, topology

[image]

I somehow ended up with these two selected edges that I do not want. I tried dissolving them, but that did not do anything. Also deleting the two faces on either side and filling them again makes it worse.
Does anyone know a trick to fix this?

Comment: Hello and welcome. you cannot. they are necessary reference point to geometry. but you can transfer the edge to another place and then dissolve the other. but there will always be an edge that leads to the inner circle.

Comment: see https://blenderartists.org/t/why-do-ngons-require-two-support-edges/1124227/15 and https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/3d_view/precision_drawing_tools/holes_in_faces.html

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/211249/110840