# Merge rectangular cubes without additional edges

Tags: modeling, mesh, export

I wanted to create a model in blender and export it into unreal to do something.

I first wanted to create windows on a wall with boolean generators. But it has some weird effects after being exported into unreal.
[image]
[image]

So I tried to split the walls into pieces and join them afterwards, but it looks like the unreal still treats them as separate objects.
[image]
[image]

My question is: how should I exactly join those meshes into one piece (the edges only exists around the windows and outside area) without those weird lighting effects? Thank you!

Comment: I think we'll need to see your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/311072/edit) your question here and paste the link into it.

Comment: @JohnEason I think they are very simple. In my second approach, each window is just surrounded by four meshes. How should I "join" them in a way such that I can treat them as a single piece without those redundant edges in between?

Comment: This is a problem with normals. It's not in Blender, but in Unreal, so you should probably solve it there.

Comment: Since you haven't included an image of your object in Edit and wireframe view it's still difficult to advise which is why I suggested that you share yor file.

Comment: For joining the faces: faces cannot have holes. A hole needs to be connected to at least two outer vertices, see dozens of questions on this topic, for example: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/210059/is-there-any-way-to-remove-edges-causing-a-loop https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/211241/dont-understand-why-holes-needs-to-be-connected-to-edge https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48954/eliminating-edges-connecting-islands

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thank you for your reply, I think I have to fix this in Unreal then.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are overlapping vertices. Press <kbd>A</kbd> to select everything, press <kbd>M</kbd> to merge, and select *By Distance*.

If anything weird happens, you may need to change the merge distance to something smaller, like `0.01m` or `0.001m`.

Comment: What do you mean by "overlapping vertices"? Two meshes are connected, then their vertices must be overlapping. Or am I understanding it incorrectly? If I merge them, blender just tells me "0 vertex deleted", so I assume it is not the problem you said.

Comment: If it says “0 vertex deleted” then yes it is not that.  I suggested it because sometimes the two meshes can appear to be connected, when in reality they are just overlapping each other, which can cause shading issues.  I suggest checking the normals, by selecting everything, and pressing Shift+N to recalculate normals.

Comment: I don't see a difference after recalculating the normals. I feel that I might just be missing some settings. Or maybe it helps in changing export/import settings?

Comment: What format are you exporting it as?  If you have the option, try selecting the option to triangulate the mesh when exporting

Comment: I'm exporting it as .fbx file, object types only meshes. In geometry, the setting is "normals only" + "apply modifiers". Which option should I enable here?

Comment: Since there’s not an option upon exporting, try selecting all and pressing ctrl+T to triangulate faces.  To make it easier to continue working, I would ctrl+Z this after you export, so you can begin working in quads again.

Comment: Looks like the triangulate faces are not helpful :/