# How do I create only one of multiple new face outcomes?

Tags: faces

I have a shape within another shape and I want to make the space between them into a new face.

[image]

I want to fill in the frame but not the actual 4 tiny squares inside.

I have tried selecting all and creating a new face but I can't seem to get that specific face. Help

Comment: You can't fill it, because [it's not a face](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/210105/35559).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is no easy way to do this automatically in your case.

You can create faces between edges manually by selecting the edges where you want the face to be, and pressing <kbd>F</kbd>.

1. Create the inner faces: Select neighboring edges, and press <kbd>F</kbd>

[image: Selecting edges]

2. Repeat this for other faces to make the inner cross:

[image: Cross faces]

3. To avoid creating non-quad geometry, we need to subdivide the outer ring to match the edge count of the inner ring. Select the outer edges (you can loop-select by using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ Click), And subdivide them with 2 cuts:

[image: Subdivision]

Now we have the same number of edges inside as outside (3 for each side). You can continue this process, making faces where needed, to fill the remaining geometry.

You can also use the [`Bridge Edge Loops` command](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/bridge_edge_loops.html) to fill multiple faces at once.

## Alternative Method

There is a much simpler way to create the window-like geometry you want:

1. Create plane
2. Subdivide for 2x2 grid
3. Set the Transform Pivot Point to "Individual origins"

[image: Individual origins]

4. Select all faces; `Extrude Individual Faces`; <kbd>Esc</kbd> to avoid offsetting
5. Scale (<kbd>S</kbd>) the 4 faces to make them smaller:

[image: Scaling]

(This will scale them individually because of step 3)

6. Delete the unnecessary faces!

Answer (score 0):

Do as the image below shows and fill the inside and the outside.
[image]