# How to make a cut on a face between an edge and a vertex?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

Basically I wanna make a cut between edge on the right and a vertex
[image]

But when I try to do it with the knife tool, it creates additional edge that I don't need

[image]

So I wonder how can I do it, since loop tool creates another cut, not between these two.

Comment: Can you share your blend file?  (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)

Comment: This might be related to the fact that all edges making a face, have to be connected into a single path. So you can't create an "O" shaped face and knife will make an additional cut to deal with this problem. Here's a screenshot of a single face, that has two pairs of overlapping vertices. Pressing A, M, B will create an abomination. https://i.imgur.com/Ia1D9IO.png

Comment: Possibly related: [Is there any way to remove edges causing a loop?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/210059/60486)

Answer (score 0):

[image]
You can just do it with the knife tool and select the edge you do not want. Then press "x" to delete it, and choose "Dissolve Edges". I hope that helps.

Comment: When i did it it deleted the edge i needed too

Comment: Then try to delete the two faces that are on each side of the unwanted edge. Then select all the edges around the hole and press "f".