# Problem with boolean modifier difference

Tags: modifiers

I'm learning Blender and I practice boolean modifier. I had a new edges created.

How can delete them to get a clean mesh ?

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Comment: You can't, Blender doesn't support faces with holes in them. See [eliminating edges connecting islands](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48954/eliminating-edges-connecting-islands) or [is there any way to remove edges causing a loop?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/210059/is-there-any-way-to-remove-edges-causing-a-loop)

Comment: @Hulifier so it wouldn't work with "dissolve edges" ?

Comment: @Karl It wouldn't, I also tested it now just to be sure.