# How to make an irregular ngon?

Tags: modeling

What I want is a shape like that,the outter and inner are complicated shape,not just circle,with different dots,only 2 ngons can fill the hole.
[image]
But when I start from just 2 lines,I can't make those 2 ngons easily.

- Click `F`,it will cover the inner hole.
  [image]
  [image]
- Click `Alt+F`,it will make many faces.
  [image]
- I add two lines,like the target shape,but the loop edge is different,it still looks like one.The target loop edge is seperate.
  [image] [image]
  [image]
  Thanks.

Comment: Blender faces [can't have unsupported holes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/210105/35559). Is this the problem? A picture of the desired _result_ would help.

Comment: @RobinBetts what I want is the 1st pic,I made it by boolean,so I think it can be done by fill,some ways.

Answer (score 3):

I don't quite know if this is what you mean.. but if you have a 2D curve comprising 2 cyclic splines, the Boolean will automatically be taken:

[image]

If the curve is given a *Decimate > Planar* modifier, then 'Convert to Mesh' will result in a minimal number of edges coonnecting the hole to the perimeter:

[image]

Comment: It's not what I want,but anyway,thanks a lot.

Comment: @NatureK can you describe, how this is not what you want? This is exactly how I understood your question. You have an inner curve (you call it a line), and an outer one, in your example those were 2 circles, but you mention in reality they are complicated shapes (so Robin made the inner curve complicated), and then he filled the space between them with 2 ngons, as you asked. The edges separating those ngons are highlighted.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Assuming that I have a complicated model,and a part of it is a hole like that,so I need to fill it.Curve is OK in some cases,but it's not reasonable to convert the  whole mesh into curves.So whether I can make it in mesh not curve?Now I think the only way is seperate the mesh,fill the hole and join them back to the mesh.

Answer (score 1):

Use bridge edge loops to start with
[image]

Select all the created edges by clicking one of them while holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>
[image]

Then dissolve them with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and turn off `Dissolve Vertices` in the popup menu
[image]

Comment: The outer and inner circle have different vertices,bridge will have trouble.If I have many vertices,it looks unreasonable to do it manually.

Comment: Another technique I use is when making text, I'll post an answer with that workflow

Answer (score 1):

When creating text I sometimes use this workflow for complex fonts:

I get to a point where I have only the boundary edges, then get the internal edges and move them off plane
[image]
[image]

Next fill everything
[image]

Then extrude the inner parts that were moved off plane so they inetrsect the rest of the text
[image]

Then with all the extruded parts selected use `Intersect Boolean` to cut out the holes
[image]

Sometimes it leaves some of the faces but they can be easily deleted
[image]
[image]

There are many hot keys and small techniques to speed this process up
Hope this helps you somehow