# How to remove triangles on this surface

Tags: modeling

Is there a way to remove the triangles on this surface?
I am new to blender and want to make some modifications to this model for 3d printing.

As a alternative modification I wanted to close the hole on this surface completely. I managed to create a new surface to close the hole, but then I wanted to extrude the new surface to fill the complete wall depth and it did not add depth to it but only moved it around.
How can I fill the hole?

[image: surface with triangles]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48954/eliminating-edges-connecting-islands

Comment: You can select the edges and then hit `X` > _Dissolve Edges_ in _Edge Select_ mode or in _Face Select_ mode select the faces and press `F` so they get merged. However, a hole always needs to be surrounded by at least two faces - a face cannot have a hole inside in Blender, so you have to keep two edges. See this answer for more information: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/210059/is-there-any-way-to-remove-edges-causing-a-loop/210105#210105