# What will be the cleanest way to remove this face?

Tags: objects, vertices, faces, .fbx

I am making a radio. These holes are meant to go all the way through, but somehow I messed up and managed to get this whole partially covered.

[image: Partially covered hole]

I am going to mess around and see if I can figure something out, but if anyone has a clean way to remove this that would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a reference of what the other holes look like.

[image: All of the holes]

Comment: hello maybe share your file and show a picture of the real object so that we can help you with some suggestions? To share file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I would delete the faces and for the gaps that might show up then (if there are no faces below the ones you deleted), select the vertices that build the gap's edges (using the vertices around the holes as well) and press F to create a new face.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48954/merge-around-a-face/48967