# My edges are overlapping. It is not the vertices

Tags: edges

The edges seems to be on top of each other. I already verified that there are no double vertices, the only problem are the edges
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edges can overlap even if vertices don't:

[image]

Comment: And how do I solve it? ;-; I could erase the edges and then reconect them, but it would be nice if there is a option to just "join" the overlapping edges in just one edge. The software cuold "see" where are overlapping edges and, if the vertices that create the edges are in line, just resume in one edge, or not?  What I just said could be dumb, I'm new to blender sorry.

Comment: @joãovitor I don't know if such tooling exists... I didn't put a lot of thought into it, but I think the problem might be far from trivial... First of all, two overlapping edges usually don't overlap ideally, because of floating point inaccuracies, I wrote about it a little [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/245230/60486). So for each vert you could look for all neighboring edges within a tolerance, and then see how far you can climb in either direction of that edge, though sometimes you could move in two directions and have to figure which is right... https://i.imgur.com/YOrLP5l.gif

Comment: Damn, to see it's such a complicate matter, no wonder I spend 2 hrs searching every place and fuction of the blender, thank you so much.