# How to fix this objects mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have this 3d model and whenever I go into edit mode, it has some weird mesh as shown on the image, it looks like the mesh is cut or it has some messed up mesh or weird geometry.

Anyone knows how to clean this up and have these lines removed? I'm new to Blender

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE! Have you tried selecting everything with `A` and then press `X` > *Limited Dissolve*.

Comment: Hello @Harry, I just tried that it fixed some things but now these are left, here is the image: https://ibb.co/rGfGTVK

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48954/eliminating-edges-connecting-islands

Comment: @annie62 just remove those vertices and fill face again

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I will try that now.

Answer (score 0):

In *Object* mode, apply the scale, then in *Edit* mode, in order to remove the overlapping vertices, select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*, and to remove all the inner edges press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve*. Then it looks like it still needs a bit of manual cleaning.

Comment: And don't forget `Shift+N` :D

Comment: It seems ok here, no?

Comment: mine had some inverted normals