# How can I fix these vertices/lines without messing up my whole mesh?

Tags: mesh, vertices

So I found out why my mesh acts weird when exporting, how can i 'smooth' those vertices / Lines without messing up the whole mesh??
[image]

Tyi

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48954/eliminating-edges-connecting-islands/48967#48967

Comment: Hi! It is because when i export it it looks like this: https://prnt.sc/nSmyr3t16mIc

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89/when-should-n-gons-be-used-and-when-shouldnt-they

Comment: thanks! I fixed it by: Go to edit mode
Navigate to the Select > All
Go to Face > Triangulate Faces