# black out of place faces in render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, faces

I've got a weird issue with this model. The mesh is fragmented when rendered, even though nothing of the sort shows up in material or solid view.

It has happened a few hours before and moving the whole mesh around and putting it back into place helped for some reason. Not this time.

There are no other faces in that space, so it's unlikely that it's z-fighting. It also seems to affect this particular part only (side panels and the front splitter are one object, separate from the rest of the body).  Any idea what I can do to fix it?

[image: borked render]

**EDIT**

As requested, I'm attaching a screen of my wireframe, together with properties. I'm using cycles.

Here's the download link: [borked wireframe](http://www.filedropper.com/308)

Also, it's working again (don't know for how long this time), even though I changed nothing. I'm starting to think it's my graphic card glitching out, though it's weird that it's affecting only one object

Comment: Never seen anything like it before. Hard to tell what it is from the pictures alone though. Can you edit your question and add more information? How are you rendering this, Cycles, internal? Van you show your mesh in the viewport, and in wireframe mode so we can see the topology? Perhaps the modifier stack and materials. If possible post your blend file

Comment: additional info posted, as requested. truth be told, it's working again so for the time being it's only academic, though I full expect it showing up again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some seriously uneven and messed up topology in your mesh, there are vertex overlapping faces, tris mixed with quads and ngons at unexpected places, all that contributes to bad topology and potential artifacts at render time.

Anyway there's an (apparently) useless and undesirable *Bevel* modifier and the end of your modifier stack causing trouble in the resulting mesh.

It is causing artifacts even in the viewport, and some more in the rendered view. Disabling it seems to mostly fix that problem.

You may want to read up on [why quad based topology is important](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2931/why-should-triangle-meshes-be-avoided-for-character-animation)

**EDIT**

You may also want to remove doubles in your mesh (under edit mode select all and <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*) and recalculate normals (under edit mode select all and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>)

Comment: but theres only a single triangle in the whole panel object? unless you're talking about the entirety of the mesh, then yeah, there might be some farts of the sort. it's my third model so i'm still grasping straws here. I got rid of bevel, hope that'll prevent it from happening in the future, I'll mark your answer as the correct one if nothing like that comes up again in this model, thanks!

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the entire mesh topology. With practice your modelling skills will certainly improve, it's hard o fix topology on finished models, so whenever starting a new one take a moment before you start to think about how it's topology will flow and how you'll proceed. A triangle here and there is not bad *per se*, but overlapping geometry, and uneven normals will certainly create problems

Comment: Also forgot to mention, don't forget to cleanup you mesh, added further info to the answer, check above.