# Are triangles bad for a mesh

Tags: animation, mesh, topology, bevel

What impact would this have on say a game asset or something like a tank that's animated ?

Asking as I'm piecing together a project that will be involving my own models.

On occasions I've noticed when Bevelling edges the create Triangles on another face, so I wanted to be certain be accepting it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a plethora of articles all over the place dealing with the subject. Like [this one](https://www.methodj.com/why-are-triangles-bad-when-modeling/), or [that one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2931/why-should-triangle-meshes-be-avoided-for-character-animation/2935).

TL;DR:

> Use whatever works. Quads are the default. But feel free to use triangles when you need to use them. There’s no hard and fast reason to say that you should never use a triangle. Sometimes it’s just easier!

Comment: Thank you, I think its because there's so many different articles its hard to get a reliable and definitive answer, some say triangles are bad others contradict it, thanks for the help bud.

Comment: Pro tip: when you can see opposite answers like that, then most of the time it's because they are all valid, but depend on their context.