# What's the reason to do all-quad modeling?

Tags: modeling, topology

After subdivision surface modifier applied tris are quad anyway.
Is there something makes sense?

Comment: The answer to "[Why should triangle meshes be avoided for character animation?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2931/why-should-triangle-meshes-be-avoided-for-character-animation)" focuses on the advantages of quad-based topology and workflow. This question is likely a duplicate.