# Which one? Single Vertice with triangles or Grid Fill?

Tags: modeling, vertices

I am working on my first non-Character Models and was modelling a Cup with the beginning mesh as a Cylinder. Now I just wanna know if it will be a problem to have the vertices on the bottom connect in a circular form so everything connects to a single vertice in the middle. or if I should Grid fill it in the middle so there are no triangles. It would mean more Vertices but I want to do it right.

[image]

So like this?

[image]

Or like this

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2931/why-should-triangle-meshes-be-avoided-for-character-animation also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89/when-should-n-gons-be-used-and-when-shouldnt-they

Comment: As long as it doesn't create any artefact it's OK to use tris, plus in your case they are within a completely co-planar surface, so there's no chance they will be noticeable