# Remove Object and part of object its overlapping

Tags: modeling, objects

How would I remove the selected object and the part of the other object taken up by it? 
[image]

Comment: Boolean operations are what you need https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lDweCpDAB_o

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack exchange, you might need to edit your question to explain better what you are willing to achieve. Remove the selected object might mean separate it to become an independent object, or might mean subtracting the selected mesh from the unselected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cut mesh at intersection](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2970/cut-mesh-at-intersection)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

Using Boolean operations:

- **In Edit mode**

Both pieces have to be part of the same object.

On the selected piece use Mesh>Faces>Intersect(Boolean)

[image]

[image]

- **In Object Mode**

Both pieces have to be different objects.

Select the one that is to be cut. And add a **[boolean modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html?highlight=boolean)** and use the other object to intersect.

[image]

This method has the advantage of being non destructive and interactive. If you need to reposition or alter the cutting object you can do it and the affected object will be recalculated.

At this point you can choose to hide other object or **Apply the Modifier** to make the change permanent and delete the cutting object.

[image]