# "Smooth Vertex" wrinkles mesh instead of smoothing it

Tags: modeling, mesh

How is this smoother, it keeps wrinkling everything like forking pie crust

[pie wrinkles http://ball2000.net/blender/images/GeeThanks.jpg](http://ball2000.net/blender/images/GeeThanks.jpg)

Comment: It seems to be caused by ngons, but not exactly sure why..

Comment: Also, could you please avoid snarky comments like the question title.  This site will become very unpleasant and useless if everyone starts lashing out and mocking other people.

Comment: I think it's that I give portions of the mesh more subdivisions than others; for now I'll just remember not to do that...

Comment: I'm thinking smooth vertex takes an average of _connected_ vertices; those vertices which moved inwards were connected by an edge to the upper curve whereas those which moved downwards weren't.  Rather than... I don't know, averaging infinity vertices of the suggested idealized shape? (may increase calculation time) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tool doesn't seem to like [ngons](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/89/599) (faces with more than four vertices).

Assuming you want to make the outer edge circular, instead you might try using *To sphere*
(<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>):

[image]

Or you might try the bundled [loops tools addon](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/LoopTools#Circle).