# Repairing bad areas in mesh

Tags: modeling

In doing [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CNbAmJ3eubo) tutorial I am "progressed" to modelling the front of the iphone. And again I have some bad areas in my mesh. I did succeed to solve some of those bad areas but have still some issues left. Who can help me with solving those issues ?

[image]

Still one issue left

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oei, jij fanatiekeling! Some to the right of nr. 2 you have a dubble edge. For 1 and 3, I dont really know what happened. Some how you also have multiple "doubles" in your mesh/object which is not good... Is it possible to go a few steps back in the tutoial and redo that part / or go back to an earlier save file where the problem has not yet occurred?

Comment: I could solve some issues, but still some issues left

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/20816/1853

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your issues are the result of the same problem: the [subsurf modifier](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/subsurf.html?highlight=ngons) will give you unpredictable, and mostly ugly, results when using [ngons](http://blog.digitaltutors.com/ngons-triangles-bad/) (polygons with more than 4 vertices).

**1** Delete this Ngon and reconnect the vertices forming quads.

[image]

**2** Other ngon... add loop cuts to keep the topology consistent using quads.

[image]

**3** Yet another ngon!:

[image]

**4** You have vertices that are going past the axis of symmetry used by the mirror modifier. That's bound to cause you more errors down the line.

Scale them to 0 in the Z axis (<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>)

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. I could solve three of four issues I think (with your instructions). One issue lef (your number two). There I don't understand your instruction. I re-uploaded my file. Start already dreaming about n-gons ;)

Comment: Now I understand your instruction for issue 2. Issue solved !!! Thanks Thanks !!

Comment: And put the Mirror mod. above the Subsurf mod.