# Blender 2.8 repair mesh

Tags: mesh

I am new to blender.

I am trying to render a fountain pen nib (a parametric surface given by a set of three complex formulae) .

I have imported the *obj file to blender, and then extruded along local normals using proportional editing on. This gives me a completely broken mesh.

See :

[image]

or with x ray on :

[image]

Obviously, the mesh is broken.

I have seen this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42288/repairing-bad-areas-in-mesh). But it seems that one has to manually correct all the faces.

Is there an automatic way to correct the mesh? I tried :

`Edit mode` > `Mesh` > `Cleanup` > `degenerate dissolve`
as well as : `decimate geometry` and `delete loose`. None of them helped. What can I do now?

Thank you

**Edit :**

the file after importing the obj (can't directly upload an obj file) :
[image]

The file after extrusion : 
[image]

Comment: can you please share the blend and obj files!?

Comment: It might help if you upload the before extrusion blend file to [our upload facility](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), State what you are trying to achieve by the extrusion. I suspect you want to use the Solidify modifier instead, but the file would help.

Comment: I have uploaded them. I cant upload an obj file, so imported it to blender and uploaded it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was *some* manual work to do. I don't know how useful this answer is, but my steps were:

- <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>.001</kbd> Bring the object to a sensible scale, and apply the scale.
- In the 3D View 'View' tab, set Near and Far Clipping to be able to see the object consistently
- Note, by enabling Face Normals in Overlays, that the object is already 2-sided
- Also note, by seeing the face-dots around the perimeter, that there are degenerate faces connecting the inside and outside.

So.

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> select the degenerate faces by similar area (0). Delete them.
2. Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> select (linked) all the inside faces and delete them.
3. Delete the bottom half of the object and replace with a Mirror modifier in Z, 'Merge' and 'Clip' checked.
4. Assign a Solidify modifier *above* the Mirror with 'Rim' *unchecked* to allow merging, towards the *inside*. This leaves  gaps which can be filled, but no intersecting faces, which you're trying to avoid.
5. When it looks good, apply the modifiers.
6. Enable the 'F2' shipped Add-On.  and use it to run round the gaps between edges, connecting by hand, (holding down <kbd>F</kbd>), because 'Bridge Edge Loops' fails somewhere, and I want to see where.
7. OK, got them, fix the topology at the points by hand. About half a dozen faces.

[image]

Bevel and subdivide, if wanted.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked.

Answer (score 2):

This is only to add some screenshot of Robins explanation of how to get your nib ready before adding the Modifiers.

1: In Object mode, Orthographic View with the nib selected open the Properties side panel with the **N** key toggle, > Item tab > Transform menu we see the nib is 10,000 times to big :
[image]

2: to correct this scale the nib by 0.0001 ( **S 0.0001 Enter** )
[image]

3 Next we need to Apply Rotations and scale. **Ctrl A** to open the Apply menu and choose the rotation and Scale option:
[image]

4: If we now switch to perspective View and zoom in on the model it will look like parts are missing. 
[image]

5: This can be corrected by reducing the Clip Start Distance to less than a millimeter.
Properties Side panel > View tab > View menu Clip start > 0.0001m :
[image]

6: Now we are ready to start the cleanup, Tab into edit mode and with the All the model selected open the Vertex menu > Merge Vertices > By distance and set the merge distance to something like 1 tenth of a millimeter, this will remove a Line of vertices along the center which may cause problems later on when using the modifiers :
[image]

7 And finally still in edit mode with everything selected open the Mesh menu > Cleanup > Delete Loose. this will remove a couple of loose edges:
[image]

Now you are ready to use the Mirror and solidify modifiers as suggested above.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I should have put in illustrations.

Comment: Thnaks, this gave me a good intro as well, but i am selecting the other answer as the best one, because it mentioned the correct modifier. i hope that's okey