# Why can't I make a vertical loop cut on this object?

Tags: modeling

I'm very new to Blender. I've got a cube object which I've manipulated with intrusion and extrusion. I'm now trying to make a vertical loop cut, but it is only being applied to the inside of my object. Horizontal loop cuts work as expected.

I've had a look at other answers and tried removing doubles, recalculating normals and had a look for any N-gons, but as far as I can tell, everything looks okay.

What can I do to make the vertical loop cut work?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. From what I can see in the picture, there still are some zero-area faces and normals that are pointing outward. Are you sure you checked everything? If you are sure this is not the problem, you can try to upload your object to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so we can inspect the scene and try to understand if there's a bug or something else. As long there is an edgeloop, it should be possible to perform loopcut operation.

Comment: Thanks! Embarrassingly, I've fixed it now. I'm not sure why, but when I first removed doubles, it didn't work (or I didn't do it properly more like!). I've done it again and can now do the vertical loop cut

Comment: Glad it helped. Could you post the link of some of the similar question where you found the answers you were mantioning so we can mark this as a duplicate (a.k.a. the solution can be found there)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Loop cut interrupted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33188/loop-cut-interrupted) and [Loop-cut won't go all the way around](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17870/loop-cut-wont-go-all-the-way-around)

Comment: Also worth reading: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/20816/1853

Comment: Thanks for the link @cegaton. I've added an answer. Even if it is a duplicate, I think it's still helpful and points towards where I found the answers in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question. There were hidden doubles in the object. Even though the original post says that this was already checked, I removed doubles again and that time it worked.

In edit mode I deselected, then reselected all and used the remove doubles tool.
<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>, `Remove Doubles`.

Making sure to set my Merge Distance greater than 0. After that, I was able to add a vertical loop cut.

The other SE questions I used to help fix this were:

- [why does loop-cut-and-slide ignore some faces but not others?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7990/why-does-loop-cut-and-slide-ignore-some-faces-but-not-others)
- [Loop-cut won't go all the way around](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17870/loop-cut-wont-go-all-the-way-around)
- [Loop cut interrupted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33188/loop-cut-interrupted)

[image]