# object deforms strangely when using the subsurf modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects, faces, subdivision-surface

I am trying to make an axe and stomped upon this problem...having no idea how to resolve it.
1st photo is with subdivision.

second is without.

[image]

[image: Without subdivision]

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34518/subdivision-surface-problem?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It basically the Ngons that are causing the problem, as Cegaton stated best to use 4 vertices to a face. So keep it even and one way can be using edge loops to create more faces evenly.

Sample solution can be like this, for example:

[image]

Fixing up the model to create quads

Summary:

- Use the *Knife Tool* to create **Quads** i.e remodel the geometry
- Use *Dissolve Edges* to keep faces, but remove edges

A Quad is just face shared by four vertices, just making that clear.

[image: The problem]

Now, you have edges lines going each of the corners vertices select them and go delete <kbd>X</kbd> > *Dissolve Edges*. This will delete your edges but keep your faces as shown here:

[image: Dissolve Edges]

TIP: Use *Edge Select* to make this easier

Now use the *Knife Tool* to create quads, what I did was use an existing vertex and created another one which creates an edge as well between the new one and the existing one. See the rectangles I'm making between those vertices, those are the new quads. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept knife changes.

**Repeat** for the rest geometry/vertices that don't have quads.

Hope that is enough :)

[image: Result of Knife]

Comment: can i solve my problem in this stage?Or how can I use only 4 vertices because i ended up there by just using basic blender tools!

Comment: Yes you can still fix from what you have [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoKgh.png). I might edit my answer to show you how.

Comment: So?any idea how to solve it?Thanks btw for all youre answers!

Comment: See my edit above for the method

Comment: I think I'm dumb...after that complex explanation I still dont get it...so I disolve some of the vertices so i remain with 4 for each "shape" but for some of them it's just not possible and with the knife tool I dont understand how to use it...Thanks for the answer

Comment: Knife tool lets you cut geometry by selecting a vertex, edge or point on a face and selecting another line, edge or point to create a 'cut'. For example if I have a plane and select one corner and then select the opposite corner I create two new faces and make an edge along the diagonal. Also, It okay if you don't understand the tool at first, google and the docs are there to help. here is the docs for the [knife tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife_subdivide.html)

Comment: Yep, he did not have enough support geometry.

Answer (score 5):

If you are just starting with blender here is lesson number one: **Avoid using n-gons** (faces with more than 4 vertices).

Ngons do not subdivide well.

Try to keep your topology using quads (4 vertices per face)

[image]

Comment: Now I have this bump!                    https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoKgh.png

Comment: besides @tacofisher's correct comment,  Don't triangulate your mesh! **Use Quads.**

Comment: I deleted my prevoius comment, I thought they had faces along the mirror axis(which sould be avoided), but looking again it does not.

Comment: and how can i solve it?

Comment: @cegaton how to detriangulate my mesh?Or simpler how to solve the problem!

Comment: @Vlad Ilisan, simply put, ADD MORE LINES.  And do some testing with different way of adding the lines, you will understand it.  You need to see and compare what's happening in relations to what you just did.  If you can not simply do that, not a single person on this website can help you.  Stop asking, just go do it, play with it, there is no reason to be afraid of doing anything wrong.  Just do it, do it wrong, learn from it.

Answer (score 3):

You have N-Gons and are using subdivision surface. N-Gons and subdivision surface don't work together unless the N-Gon is flat and surrounded by a quad loop. This is not the case in your model. See [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/95/26720) for more details on when Ngons are okay to use.

Comment: Now I have this! https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoKgh.png

Answer (score 0):

Subsurf needs quads but also objects created with **Spin** and proportional editing to have the desired effect without extra work. A bowling pin is an example of sich an object.