# Subdividing Causes Strange Edges / Issues on Shape

Tags: mesh, vertices, edges, subdivision-surface

So I have this flat shape, and I'm trying to make it 3D. It's pretty round and has a ton of vertices. My end goal is to have the 3D shape with smooth edges.

[image: An outline of a round shape made with vertices]

I approached this by pressing ALT+F to fill the shape. It created a bunch of faces that don't look too clean.

[image: I filled the shape by pressing ALT+F]

Then I extruded the shape once forward, and once back (from the original shape) so that it was "3D". This is close to what I want, but I want it to have a subdivision modifier, so the edges look smooth.

[image: I extruded the shape to be "3D"]

I then applied a subdivision modifier, and the shape just looks awful. Bumpy and ugly.
[image: When applying a subdivision modifier, the shape looks bad. Bumpy edges.]

If I do "F" instead of ALT +F, it still produces a poor result.
[image: If I do "F" instead of ALT +F, it still produces a poor result]

I've tried looking on this forum for solutions to similar issues, but so far not much has worked. I hope the images are enough to paint my issue, and give an idea of what I'm trying to achieve, any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This is topology issue. Subdivision Surface modifier do not work well with ngons and tris.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82392/object-deforms-strangely-when-using-the-subsurf-modifier and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34518/subdivision-surface-problem or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82392/object-deforms-strangely-when-using-the-subsurf-modifier Also see http://topologyguides.com/

Comment: @LukeD I'm not fully aware with how I would go about fixing that as I'm not necessarily familiar with ngons.

Comment: Please upload your file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and maybe I could make something out of it. The main thing is that (as you should know from all the links that Duarte provided) you need quad based topology.

Comment: @LukeD
I appreciate your willingness to help. I added the link to the .blend file, if you figure it out, please share how you did so in detail so I can try it myself.

Answer (score 2):

[image: topo]

It's not the best topology but just quick example.

First thing I've done was to delete half of the mesh and add **Mirror modifier** to reduce work.

Next I've created **Outer Edge Loop** just by extruding vertices.

In the same manner I've filled rest of the mesh with faces with some **Reduction Loops**, this was needed for making all of the faces quads (more on this you can find on topologyguides.com).

I haven't used any "automatic" methods, it's just extruding <kbd>E</kbd> and filling <kbd>F</kbd> with a little help from **F2 add-on**. It's all manual work.

Comment: I personally feel like this answer is the way to go. Especially if the OP plans to rig this model in some way. The TRI topology would make rigging and deformation a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a bulk of verts.

In the edit mode select the verts and make few edges

In the Transform panel. Select the outer edge and Make crease 1

Add subsurf modifier and extrude

[image]