# How to avoid extraneous edges when using loop cut?

Tags: modeling, edges, topology, geometry, optimization

In order to create the detail for the shape on the right of the image below:

[image]

I had to create a lot of loop cuts. But the loop cuts create all the extra edges further to the left of the model, which don't really serve a purpose. I'm trying to create this as an asset for a game, so keeping it low-poly is important. How could I have modeled it without creating so many extra edges? Should I just create an extra mesh (in the same object)?

Comment: If this is a hard-surface model that will not need to deform or be subsurfed, I think you should be okay using n-gons. If it does need to deform, probably best to invest time in creating topology with edge flow that minimizes extraneous geometry.

Comment: It truly depends on what's the puropse of the model (see [What's the best way to topologize this?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35489/whats-the-best-way-to-topologize-this)). Surely ripping the edges would probably be the most efficent way to lower the polycount, but then you'll have two disjoined pieces. Would it be fine?

Comment: If we are talking about game engine here then it doesn't matter whether you have edge line showing or not. Just remember game engine see your mesh as triangles. So if you have a polygon (4 vertices) it's equal to 2 triangles. If you have a pentagon it can be represented with just 3 triangles. So a pentagon  ngon without any edge showing up in it's surface does count as 1 face in a game engine.

Comment: It's a common belief among modellers that all models ought to be formed from a single seamless mesh. However, one of the simplest ways to model this type of object is to create the mesh as separate pieces.

Answer (score 1):

In this **specific case**, I think think the best thing is to use the *cut* tool <kbd>k</kbd>.

In specific answer to your question, the way to create a loop cut, without having it go all the way down the surface, is ripping an edge <kbd>v</kbd>. In your case, you would rip the edge right along the extrusion, and the front edge to the right of it. Then make your loop cuts. You can then mend the edges if you wish, by deleting the extra edge (will remove the face of the wall), adding faces (such as tris, because in the game engine it converts to tris anyway) or by making an n-gon face over the whole section.

I hope this helps. If you give me your blend file I can make examples.

Comment: You don't need to rip - you can just hide the faces. Hiding faces will stop an edge loop continuing.

Answer (score -1):

In this case, what I would do is make the area that requires a lot of loop cuts into a second object. I tried to avoid doing that at first, but there's no reason to. The computer is calculating face and vertex data. By having the extended part of the mesh as a separate object, you reduce the vertices in the first object, because the loop cuts can be removed altogether.

Select the extruded area of your mesh, separate it (I changed all my shortcuts so I have no idea what the default one is), and dissolve all of the old surplus edges in the other object.

It will stay low poly, and is just as easy to unwrap and manipulate. Just parent it to the old object if you'd like it to move at the same time, or group it, or whatever. Lots of options in this case.

Separate objects are good. Try downloading a couple of models from the Models Resource, you'll be amazed how often things are separated into multiple objects when they seem like they must be a single object.