# The right way of modeling half circles

Tags: modeling, topology

So I'm modeling a window for a scene and used a half circle and the boolean modifier to create a half circle in a mesh.

On the right side you see the cuts I made using the knive tool to create quats and tri's.

On the left side you see just 1 face that I created by selecting all the verts of creating a face.

Is there any partical reason why I should with left or right? As far I can tell left just add's more verts to my scene.

[image: Example]

Comment: There is no absolute right or wrong. Each topo has it's pro's and con's, using one or another depends on the workflow you have in mind and the purpose of the modeling. Can you tell a bit more about them? Is the window co-planar to the wall? Are you planning to deform it with lattice? Are you struggling in keeping the scene low-poly?

Comment: Related questions: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89/when-should-n-gons-be-used-and-when-shouldnt-they/95#95 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35489/whats-the-best-way-to-topologize-this and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27780/topology-question-regarding-circular-holes

Comment: It's currently just a cut out in the wall. The window it self is going to be a separate object. The wall it self will not get deformed, although it would be nice to have the option to do so later.

Comment: "Modeling half-circles" usually means making new objects, rather than the hole-cutting you're talking about; might want a better title and add a picture a  an angle that shows you're talking about cuts.

Comment: Also, for most purposes you don't have to be exact about a cut like this. Your hole only needs to be accurate enough that wall doesn't show in the window and hole doesn't show outside, if the trim is wide the hole can be lower res. This doesn't apply if you're trying to model something to be built or possibly if the joint is involved in poly-specific physics, but it's true for most art/display purposes.