# How would you clean this mesh up?

Tags: modeling

I inserted edge loops to create the 'windows' but I have now so many faces. What should I do to have a clean topology without changing the geometry?

[image]

If I remove the edges in the middle of the windows (Dissolve Edges option) I loose the geometry. So I don't know how I can clean this mesh up?
[image]
[image]
Here is the original geometry I want to keep.
[image]

Comment: Updated...see below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>ALT</kbd> select edges in Edge Mode, and <kbd>X</kbd> - dissolve.

[image: dissolve edges]

Update: In response to your Sub-div issue. Instead of just removing geometry, you might look at how you are modeling. In the example below I have made the windows edge loops. The one on the left is all quads, and the one on the right has one N-gon in the window - if you don't mind N-gons. The advantage of this geometry can be noted on the sides [top & bottom] where less faces are needed.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I use a subdivision surface modifier. If I remove the edges inside the 'windows' will this not affect the geometry?

Comment: If it is only the sub-surf modifier- the shape will probably change at the corners. If your edges are Marked Sharp and have edge crease of 1 - they will not be affected.

Comment: thnaks. There can be issues with N-gones?

Comment: Yes and no. Nice explanation here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89/when-should-n-gons-be-used-and-when-shouldnt-they